# Python - Delete a character from list or string

Tags: python, string, list

If the verb ends in e, drop the e and add -ing.

I'm inputing a string (English verb). And my goal is to delete last char of the word if it's "e". And add 3 more characters "i","n" and "g".

I'd like to know how to delete the list object or if possible a string character. And how to switch a list into a string.

Currently im on.

```
if verb_list[-1] == ["e"]:              #verb_list is a inputed string putted into a list
    verb_list[-1] = "i"
    verb_list.append("n")
    verb_list.append("g")
```

This isnt a proper solution for me. I'd like to know how to delete for example [-1] element from list or from string. Also here im left with a list, and i want my output to be a string.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This will replace all `e`'s in each string with `ing`

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice

```
if verb[-1]=='e':
    verb = verb[:-1]+"ing"
```

For more about slicing in Python - [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/)

Comment: What that means? verb[:-1]

Comment: @h0ax It removes the last character of a string. A more 'normal' example would be [0:4]. That takes the first 4 characters of a string. Minus means that instead of countring from the front it starts counting from the end. So -1 is the last character. So [:-1] can also be written as [0:-1] which means, take everything from the string from the start until the last character.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i understand well!

Comment: @h0ax Have updated answer so you can see how slicing works

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
re.sub('e$', 'ing', s)
```

The `$` in the regex matches the pattern only if it's at the end of a string.

Example usage:

```
import re

data = ['date', 'today', 'done', 'cereal']

print([re.sub('e$', 'ing', s) for s in data])
#['dating', 'today', 'doning', 'cereal']
```

I know the words in `data` aren't verbs but those were words off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is too complicated for me for now to use and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
li=list(verb)
if li[-1]=='e':
    li[-1]='ing'
    verb=''.join(li)
```

Comment: Thats also a nice and simple solution. Can you tell me how ''.join() exactly working ?

Comment: The join() method takes all items in an iterable and joins them into one string. Syntex: string_name.join(iterable) . For example: 

list1 = ['1','2','3','4'] 

'-'.join(list1)

Result would be: 1-2-3-4

Comment: How join works in python, please follow the link: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join

Comment: @h0ax upvote it, if it helps in your case so that others also get the benefit.